# Matlab cannot invoke Microsoft Powerpoint or Word with ActiveX

Tags: matlab, com, activex, powerpoint, invoke

My Matlab R2015b code is:

```
x = actxserver('PowerPoint.Application');
invoke(x.Presentations,'Open','C:\ESL\cTemplate.ppx');
```

The first line works.  I can inspect x and see that it has found Microsoft PowerPoint.

The second line yields

> Error using Interface.91493462_5A91_11CF_8700_00AA0060263B/Open.

Invoking other PowerPoint commands yield the same error.  Similar code to open a document with Word yields

> Error using Interface.0002096C_0000_0000_C000_000000000046/Open.

I can open an Excel workbook with the `invoke` command.  I tried replacing PowerPoint 2010 with PowerPoint 2007 to no effect.  I tried changing Office's Trust Center ActiveX settings to no effect.  Coworkers with Office 2007 and Matlab R2015b are not having this problem.

What am I missing?

Comment: Never mind.  Reinstallation of Matlab R2015b solved the problem.